# Why RPM dependencies does not allow me to upgrade to an older version?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

Here's the problem, I generated these 2 rpms that are dependent

> Name: rpmtest
>
> Version: 1.0.0
>
> Release: 13
>
> Name: rpmtestApp
>
> Version: 1.0.0
>
> Release: 13
>
> Requires: rpmtest >= 1.0.0-13

this is for release 13 and I also generated the rpms for version 15

> Name: rpmtest
>
> Version: 1.0.0
>
> Release: 15
>
> Name: rpmtestApp
>
> Version: 1.0.0
>
> Release: 15
>
> Requires: rpmtest >= 1.0.0-15

So If i install version 15 and after I install version 13, I should get a message that 15 is newer than 13 and is already installed but that is not what I get :

> -> rpm -Uhv rpmtest-1.0.0-15.x86_64.rpm
>
> Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
>
> 1:rpmtest                ########################################### [100%]
>
> -> rpm -Uhv rpmtestapp-1.0.0-15.x86_64.rpm
>
> Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
>
> 1:rpmtestapp             ########################################### [100%]
>
> -> rpm -Uhv rpmtest-1.0.0-13.x86_64.rpm
>
> error: Failed dependencies:
>
> rpmtest >= 1.0.0-15 is needed by (installed) rpmtestapp-1.0.0-15.x86_64

Why does'nt it look to see if it will be upgraded or not, before looking at the Requires of `rpmtestapp-1.0.0-15.x86_64` !!!

if I do

> -> rpm -Uhv rpmtestapp-1.0.0-13.x86_64.rpm
>
> Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]

package `rpmtestapp-1.0.0-15.x86_64` (which is newer than `rpmtestapp-1.0.0-13.x86_64`) is already installed

that was the result I also expected for `rpmtest-1.0.0-13.x86_64.rpm` !

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: I created a rmp rpmTestApp that requires a specific version of rpmtest rpm. Why I'am not able to updagre to a prevoius version without errors?

Comment: I don't get the question either... Everything looks fine to me. App version 15 needs lib version 15. You can't install lib version 13 when app is 15.

Comment: If you want both app and lib to be downgraded to 13, you can install them both on the same command line.

Comment: I do not want the lib/app to be downgraded. I just want to run rpm -Uhv \*15\*.rpm to installs the lib15 and app15 and if after I run rpm -Uhv \*13\*.rpm I would like rpm to tell me that 15 is newer and already installed for both app and lib. Instead I'm getting an error when installing lib13 that says that app15 needs lib15, but it is not a real error because lib13 won't upgrade lib15 because lib15 is newer and already installed!!

Comment: So the real question is: Is there a way by using provides/requires or anything  to have that combinaison : app15 requires lib >=15  and if I try to install app13 that requires lib >=13 it just says that 15 is newer and already installed for both app and lib?